# Why a u-turn instead of an "n-turn"?

Tags: expressions

I'm sure we all know what a "u-turn" is. However, people seem to go from the top of the U. Wouldn't an "n-turn" make more sense, because driving logistics force you to go in more the shape of a lowercase "n", from your perspective.

Comment: It's in the shape of a "U" from your perspective AFTER you finish the turn.

Comment: @ChrisSunami that could be an answer.

Comment: Language is as it is, not as you or anybody else think it should be.

Comment: Presumably the same reason a T junction doesn't look like t

Comment: In noncursive handwriting, I render the letter 'u' as a simple curve, but I render the lowercase letter 'n' as vertical line downward, then retraced upward, followed by a curve similar to a partial 'u' curve in reverse. My handwritten 'n' path is thus quite unlike the path that a vehicle follows in making a U-turn, whereas my handwritten 'u' path follows a trajectory very similar to it. Admittedly, a mathematical 'intersection' symbol (∩) would be even more apt as a reference symbol (especially for U-turns at intersections)—but "intersection symbol turn" doesn't exactly glide off the tongue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shape of an "N" is ambiguous (upper or lower) but the shape of a "U" is not.

Answer (score 5):

Most critical traffic instruction signs are written in capital letters, such as

- STOP
- LEFT TURN
- DEAD END
- MERGE RIGHT etc.

This is so that it can be clearly seen from a distance.

As mentioned by Chris Sunami upper case "u" is still "U" making it unambiguous, whereas  n becomes N which *is ambiguous*, irrespective of the sign looking like a "n" however in written form it is U.

[image]